# Didn't receive message in messaging.onMessage event when loosing the focus firebase with react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, service-worker

When I lose focus I didn't receive message in `messaging.onMessage` event however I receive the message in event `messaging.onBackgroundMessage` in SW file which is included in the public folder.
The question here is how can I pass the data from SW file to Notification file to display it

SW File:

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  const notificationTitle = 'new notification';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: '',
    icon: '',
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Notification file:

```
      messaging?.onMessage((payload) => {
        console.log(payload, 'payload');
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by passing message from onBackgroundMessage to the client and in client code I listened to the message from service worker

here is what I did :

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(messaging, payload => {
  self.clients
    .matchAll({
      type: 'window',
      includeUncontrolled: true,
    })
    .then(all =>
      all.forEach(client => {
        client.postMessage(payload);
      })
    );
    ...
```

and in client code :

```
  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function handler(event) {
        console.log(event)
      });
```