# Angular and ASP.NET Core: firebase cloud messaging not receive any message

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have installed Firebase to angular and I have the following code:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'auth-domain',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'storage-buc',
  messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
  measurementId: 'mesasure-id'
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
  // ...
});

getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'firebase-vapid-key' })
  .then((currentToken) => {
    if (currentToken) {
      console.log(currentToken);
      this.refreshFCMTokenAndSubscribe(currentToken);

      // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
      // ...
    } else {
      // Show permission request UI
      console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      // ...
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    // ...
  });
```

I call this method in the Back-end (.net core):

```
[HttpPost("RefreshFCMTokenAndSubscribe")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshFCMTokenAndSubscribe(string fcmToken)
{
    await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SubscribeToTopicAsync(
            new[] { fcmToken }, "WeatherTopic");

    return Ok();
}
```

When I send a message using Firebase. The message sent successfully but I didn't receive any message in the Angular app.

I also tried to subscribe to topics from angular like this, I got an http 401 unauthorized error:

```
public subscribeToFirebaseTopics(fcmToken: string, topic: string): void {
fetch('https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/' + fcmToken+ '/rel/topics/' + topic, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Authorization': `key=${firebase-vapid-key}`
  })
}).then(response => {
  if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 400) {
    throw 'Error subscribing to topic: ' + response.status + ' - ' + response.text();
  }
  console.log('Subscribed to "' + topic + '"');
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
}
```

Have I missed anything? please help

Answer (score 0):

After some search I found this solution:

I know I have to add 'firebase-messaging-sw.js' file to src folder
but what I missed is this code inside the file:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': 'sender-id'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

and that's it.

And from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75446148/1423781 for receiving message you have to include this code in index.html:

```
navigator.serviceWorker
.addEventListener('message', 
function handler(event){
  console.log(event);
  // here you can do any thing you want when receiving message like:
let notificaiotnsCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('newNotifications')?? '0');
  notificaiotnsCount++
  localStorage.setItem('newNotifications', notificaiotnsCount);
},
);
```